# Photoshop CS2 under Wine 1.4 Messes up Unity Desktop

Tags: unity, compiz, wine, photoshop

I'm aware that the general consensus is that Photoshop is at best barely usable under Wine. I'm one of the lucky few that got CS2 (apparently one of the least quirky) running well under Wine 1.4 in Ubuntu 12.04. All the mentioned quirks like the crashes provoked by the text tool are not present. With the -for my practical purposes- unimportant exception of Bridge refusing to start, the rest is working just fine.

The only grave quirk it has is that on closure, it messes up completely the Unity desktop, lossing automatically the 3D appearance, **leaving me with a D2 desktop, square cornered windows and *without* the (x)(-)([]) buttons** and windows title. This forces me to close the windows by means of Ctrl-Q and eventually a reboot to get back the correct desktop and window appearance.

In the likely case there's no solution to this behaviour, **is there a command or script I may use to restore the usual desktop?** That would allow me to place a launcher to that effect.

I'll appreciate any comment not in the lines of looking for a Photoshop substitute. I've been through all and they won't let me do in a practical manner what I need.

Many thanks in advance.

Jorge.

[image: Photoshop running, normal desktop]

[image: Photoshop closed, messed desktop. Note the lack of buttons and the square corners]

---

**Update 27.05.2012 14:20 CST:**

[Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) and [Alvin](https://askubuntu.com/users/36285/alvin) have helped me to pinpoint the problem to the 3D session. Thus, so far the solution involves logging-out of the 3D session and logging back-in with a 2D session *before* starting Photoshop; then it exits normally and doesn't disturb the desk.

Of great help would be **a way to switch-off the 3D effects without having to log-out, and then back-on**, if it is at all feasible. **Of even greater help** would be a BASH script to automate this.

---

**Update 27.05.2012 19:10 CST:**

jasmines' suggestion to do a `compiz --replace` doesn't terminate correctly, although while the order is still in a loop the desktop appears normal. However, closing the terminal or breaking the loop reverts the session status to a crippled desk, no top panel, no launcher, no window top bar & controls and now; **no keyboard**.

The final output of the *compiz --replace* where it gets stuck is this:

```
WARN  2012-05-27 20:44:32 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No existe la interfaz «org.ayatana.bamf.view» en el objeto en la ruta /org/ayatana/bamf/application62801462

WARN  2012-05-27 20:44:32 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No existe la interfaz «org.ayatana.bamf.view» en el objeto en la ruta /org/ayatana/bamf/application62801462
```

Hopefully somebody can decode this. It's sanskrit to me. 
The solution to the problem is still at large...

---

**SOLVED!**

See [virpara](https://askubuntu.com/users/40166/virpara)'s answer. I created the script by his suggestion and placed a launcher to it in my desktop. Works like a charm and solves my Photoshop exit bad manners in less than a minute :-)

Adding 3 screen captures of *before, during and after*.

[image: Photoshop running, desktop normal]

[image: Photoshop closed, desktop ruined]

[image: After running **"Restore Unity"** script, desktop back to normal]

Beautiful. This place is a wealth of knowledge. Many thanks to all who participated.

Comment: C'mon guys! Someone must have an idea how to reset Unity without rebooting... I tried *unity --restore* in a terminal and it vanished the top panel and launcher <aaargh!>. At everything came back to normal after a reboot. Iḿ thinking that a current --CS5.1/CS6?- Photoshop in a VM or rebooting into Winsloth will be the best (only?) solution.

Comment: Do you mean you used `unity --reset`? (`--restore` is not a valid flag for `unity`.) What happens when you press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, log in (you won't see anything as you type in your password, that's fine), run `compiz --display :0 --replace`, then press `Alt`+`F7`?

Comment: have you tried booting to unity 2d and see if the same bug is present?

Comment: Don't worry, I'll post an answer if I feel like I have one that is really going to work (there's a week left on the bounty anyways). Meanwhile, if somebody else makes an answer based on the troubleshooting we're doing, and it works and they put in the work to make it thorough and well-presented, I certainly have no problem with them getting the bounty. With that said...is your goal just to avoid rebooting, or you you want to avoid having to log out and back in after running Photoshop CS2? If you're OK with logging out, there's: `Alt`+`F2`, `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper`.

Comment: A script to log out is certainly feasible. I don't know about logging back in automatically. You might be able to restart the GUI without actually logging out. Hopefully someone else can weigh in on these questions. Are you able to log out? Does manually invoking `gtk-logout-helper` work for logging out?

Comment: Hey guys - you got some really good stuff buried in the comments - Jorge please update your question with your thoughts.  Eliah - please create an answer (start with "answer in progress") - and both, tidy up by deleting these comments.  Thanks!

Comment: @fossfreedom Will do. (I should be able to get to this pretty soon.)

Answer (score 4):

*answering because is says `script to restore Unity 3D without rebooting will do.`*

create a file wherever you like(I will create in `/usr/bin`)

`gksudo gedit /usr/bin/restore-unity` give pass and paste

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo killall compiz
compiz --replace
```

in gedit then close gedit. now you have script named `restore-unity` in `/usr/bin/`.
give execution permission.

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/restore-unity`

to run, open terminal and run

`restore-unity`

## Note:

run this as command( <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> ). if you run this from terminal you have to keep terminal running if you interrupted or closed terminal thing will get messed up.

Or

to make it persistent even if terminal is closed just use prefix `nohup`

thats it.

Comment: Many thanks! This nicely rounds up what jasmines proposed as terminal commands. It can even be invoked by a desktop launcher. Unfortunately my problem seems to have evolved: the `compiz --replace` command gets stuck in what seems an endless loop and has to be terminated with a *Ctrl+C*. This would be the perfect solution as while it is running the desktop and windows almost recover their normal appearance but as the command is (abnormally) terminated or the terminal forcefully closed, the desk reverts to its crippled state. Please check the comments for the exit warnings.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you please read **note**

Comment: OK, I'll have to log-out and back in as I already have it running in a terminal window to test again but will be back in a couple min.

Comment: Success!!! Many many thanks. Works like a charm. Followed your modified recipe to the letter and made a launcher. My desktop returned. Thereś a slight -unimportant- change; it lost the laiuncher color tweak but it's nimious. I'll add the images to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Is compiz still running?
If so, try kill it and then restart it:

```
sudo killall compiz
compiz --replace
```

Report back for errors!

#### *Jorge M. Treviño(OP) wrote( these are comments by OP i have included for future reference):*

`sudo killall compiz` left me without a keyboard, I couldn't issue the next command  but `sudo killall compiz && compiz --replace` gave me this output:

```
(compiz:5223): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed Initializing unityshell options...done 
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture 
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture Starting gtk-window-decorator 
WARN 2012-05-27 15:01:52 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon. 
WARN 2012-05-27 15:01:52 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0
```

Similar warnings followed... I don't know how to place them here.Then

```
(compiz:5223): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed Initializing unityshell options...done 
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture 
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
```

and more Warnings...

Finally,

```
ERROR 2012-05-27 15:01:53 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 
g_object_unref: assertion G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

but YES! that got me back the top panel, the launcher and the 3D windows!

Oops! Hold your horses please guys. I was hasty saying it solved the problem.

The terminal was stuck just after the output `G_IS_OBJECT (object)` failed and I didn't notice that I didn't get a prompt back. Breaking the `compiz --replace` order with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> left me with the crippled desk again. I'm going to try this again in 2D mode and see what happens...

No go, the output is:

```
(compiz:30135): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed Initializing unityshell options...done
WARN 2012-05-27 20:44:32 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No existe la interfaz «org.ayatana.bamf.view» en el objeto en la ruta /org/ayatana/bamf/application62801462
```

OK, the sum is this: `compiz --replace`, even in a 2D session ends stuck in an error loop with two warnings about the `interface «org.ayatana.bamf.view» not existing.` Terminating the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> cripples the desk. Again, ideas?

*these were the comments by OP though he has solved it now( for future reference)*

Comment: `sudo killall compiz` left me without a keyboard, I couldn't issue the next command <g> but `sudo killall compiz && compiz --replace` gave me this output: *following on next comment*

Comment: `(compiz:5223): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
Starting gtk-window-decorator
WARN  2012-05-27 15:01:52 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2012-05-27 15:01:52 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0`

Comment: Similar warnings followed... I don't know how to place them here.

Comment: Then: (compiz:5223): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture and more Warnings...

Comment: Finally, `ERROR 2012-05-27 15:01:53 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
` but **YES! that got me back the top panel, the launcher and the 3D windows!!!** Bless you man! *(off to lunch...)*

Comment: remember this is a question and answer site so all of your comments should be added to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom It seems this this answer was the key, so if [jasmines](http://askubuntu.com/users/32230/jasmines) (or somebody) can edit it to provide details (for example, about how the problem might be that `compiz` wasn't quitting like it was supposed to even when another instance was started with `--replace`), I think it would be best for [jasmines](http://askubuntu.com/users/32230/jasmines) to get the bounty. Given this, do you still want me to make an "answer in progress"? This seems to me unnecessary, now that we have an answer that works.

Comment: This is something I'll leave to you guys to decide.  I'm keen to get a question & answer with as much of the comments in to help people in the future.  Comments will be removed in the future ... and as such the information currently hidden away in the comments will be lost.

Comment: @jasmines Oops! Hold your horses please guys. I was hasty saying it solved the problem. The terminal was stuck just after the output *G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed* and I didn't notice that I didn't get a prompt back. Breaking the `compiz --replace` order with a *Ctrl-C* left me with the crippled desk again. I'm going to try this again in 2D mode and see what happens...

Comment: No go, the output is: <br> (compiz:30135): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done  
<br>WARN  2012-05-27 20:44:32 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No existe la interfaz «org.ayatana.bamf.view» en el objeto en la ruta /org/ayatana/bamf/application62801462
<br><br>
WARN  2012-05-27 20:44:32 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: No existe la interfaz «org.ayatana.bamf.view» en el objeto en la ruta /org/ayatana/bamf/application62801462

Comment: OK, the sum is this: `compiz --replace`, even in a 2D session ends stuck in an error loop with two warnings about the interface «org.ayatana.bamf.view» not existing. Terminating the loop with Ctrl-C cripples the desk. Again, ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think, "compiz --replace" is bad idea.

Just use Alt-F2, "compiz-decorator" - will restore frames without compiz restart.

Comment: **Great Solution! Probably the best.** Works perfectly and takes a fraction of a second. I'm sorry you didn't catch the bounty. I've added a launcher to it in my desktop so I don't have to be hunting for it, in case it's really broken.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to restore the menus with a:

> kill -HUP `pidof compiz`

but I'd much rather it didn't die. If anyone hears of a fix for the problem(s) causing the crash, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note - you're probably experiencing a known bug in 12.04 & wine that affects many programs in wine, though others are ok

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/993265

Comment: Doug, you spotted it precisely (pun intended <g>). Let's hope Wine 1.5 has corrected this; I haven't tried to install it as there's no .deb package yet and frequently new versions of Wine introduce as many new bugs as they solve. So far, thus, the solution offered by virpara gives me an acceptable workaround. **Many thanks for the heads-up on the bug**; it prevents me from exhausting myself looking for a solution to a problem I thought particular to my setup.