# everything changed in my Desktop after running a command, can anyone help?

Tags: 12.04, unity-greeter

after i executed `unity-greeter` command in terminal, my theme changed into classic gnome and my icons too.
and even some of my icons have been deleted !
i tried to change some files like `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` to change defaults of my session but it was useless .
can anyone help me to revert my settings back ?

Comment: Can you post your /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf?
Will you get the old session back if you log out and re-log in choosing the correct session manager (gnome-shell or unity I suppose)?

Comment: i have copied an original copy of `lightdm.conf` ( i had backed it up before any changes ) to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` but no change was made

Comment: You're answering to some other question...

Comment: @jasmines No. The OP is answering the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [answers to a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141802/photoshop-cs2-under-wine-1-4-messes-up-unity-desktop) I had. Quoting from there:

```
sudo killall compiz && compiz --replace
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `unity --reset` as well. :-)

Comment: i tried it but no change was made :(